# Adding letters to a cell in excel, python

Tags: excel, openpyxl, worksheet

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('student.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


# Write letters to different cells
sheet['A1'] = 'A'
sheet['B1'] = 'B'
sheet['C1'] = 'C'
sheet['D1'] = 'D'
sheet['E1'] = 'E'

# Save the workbook
wb.save('student.xlsx')
```

I have an excel workbook that is open and called student.  The workbook is completely empty with one sheet called "Sheet1".  I am trying to just add letters to the the first row of each column and when I run the code I get no errors, however my excel workbook is not updated

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Are you sure the `save` is overwriting the original workbook?

Comment: Do you have the workbook open in Excel at the same time?

Comment: Yes the workbook is also open at the same time

Comment: Then you should expect to get a permission error when saving the file (so the file will not be saved).